# SQL Query for extracting rate and date started and ended for the table and data shown

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I had an interview today and there was a hands on test which had the following Rate and Date column. The  question was to write a query that would output the rate, date started and date ended for that rate. Rates are repeated many times and in the example below, 3.5 can appear again after 4.5 or 5 or later rows;

```
Rate Date
3.5  20/01/2014
3.5  18/02/2014
.
.
3.5  20/03/2015
4.5  14/04/2015
4.5  19/05/2015
.
.
4.9  30/05/2015
3.5  28/06/2015
```

I didn't know how to, but was playing around Window functions, but the interviewers weren't looking satisfied with my approach :( Please someone help me understand a query for this?

***I think that question had expected output results as follows (if i remember correctly)***

```
 Rate StartEndDate
    3.5  20/01/2014 
    3.5  28/06/2015
    4.5  14/04/2015
    4.5  19/05/2015
```

Comment: Can you please provide the results they expected.

Comment: @holder: Done thank you for asking

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One method is to use a difference of row number:

```
select rate, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by rate order by date) as seqnum_r
      from t
     ) t
group by rate, (seqnum - seqnum_r);
```

To understand why this works, you need to start at the results of a subquery for a while.  You will then "get" why the difference identifies the groups you want.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I did something similar for the inner query but interviewer told that if I partition by rate, I will still have rate at below rows repeating, how can I do he asked. Well do you mind explaining me what is t.* and the from( syntax which I never came across as I am a beginner level expertise.

Comment: Would you also please help showing me in some output window a sample data/table and query? I can try that myself in my sql..

Comment: @Learner results of this query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/750517/max-and-min-inslands

Answer (score 0):

for the output you are suggesting is it not just:

```
select 
    rate
    , min(date)
from 
    rnd 
group by 
rate

union

select 
    rate
    , max(date)
from 
    rnd 
group by 
    rate
```

e.g.:https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/750504/max-and-min-in-the-same-column