# Splitting data into time intervals according to changes (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-range

Let's say I have two tables:

**Salary**:

```
PersonId, StartDate, EndDate, Salary
```

**Title**:

```
PersonId, StartDate, EndDate, Title
```

The salary of a person is independent of his title, either may change at any time.

How can I best get all the consecutive StartDate/EndDate time intervals during which salary and title don't change?

So this...

**Salary**

```
Me | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31 | 2000
Me | 2017-02-01 | 2017-05-31 | 2100
Me | 2017-06-01 | 2017-07-31 | 2300
```

**Title**

```
Me | 2017-01-01 | 2017-03-31 | Junior
Me | 2017-04-01 | 2017-07-31 | Senior
```

would return:

**SalaryAndTitle**

```
Me | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31 | 2000 | Junior
Me | 2017-02-01 | 2017-03-31 | 2100 | Junior
Me | 2017-04-01 | 2017-05-31 | 2100 | Senior
Me | 2017-06-01 | 2017-07-31 | 2300 | Senior
```

This is a simplified example. In my real case there would be many changing columns, and the resulting data set should still contain time intervals where those columns have unchanged values with respect to that time period.

I'm thinking about `over( partition by...)` but I can't get it to work. Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

Kim

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the performance requirements you have and i am sure there will be better ways of doing this, however....

one sort of catch all solution to these problems is to break it down day by day and then use standard aggregate functions, for example below I am assuming you have a table called dates that has all the dates you are interested in:

```
select 
    p.personid
    ,min(ds.dt) as from 
    ,max(ds.dt) as to
    ,s.salary
    ,t.title
from
    dates as ds
    cross join 
        (select distinct personid from salary) as p
    left outer join salary as s
        on ds.dt >= s.startdate
        and ds.dt <= s.enddate
        and p.personid = s.personid
    left outer join title as t
        on ds.dt >= t.startdate
        and ds.dt <= t.enddate
        and p.personid = t.personid
group by
    p.personid
    ,s.salary
    ,t.title
```

I am using left outer joins here as i would start with that and do some analysis of the data.

I use this type of thing for analysis, reporting and data migration a lot. I have used it for billing calculations too - however I have done absolutely no performance testing on this type of approach. the focus has been writing queries that are easy to maintain and have all the power you could ever want (analysis tends to be easyier with highly de-normalised data like a day by day breakdown)

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to get this as efficient as possible. I also think (without actually trying it) that there is a problem with your solution: if I later return to the same salary and title combination that I've had previously (having had a different combination in between), the min/max will set the span of that combination from the first date the combination occurred to the last date the same combination occurred, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: everyone always wants max efficiency :D.. you can add any other column from the title and salary tables to the select and group by to ensure that doesn't happen i guess. this potentially related answer i saw the other day from gordon-linoff may help but i have not got around to figuring out the exact working of it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055261/359135

Comment: also.. i don't know if this is in-efficient or not, I have certainly analysed millions of records this way without issue, may be worth giving it a go with your real data (e.g. if you are only looking at one employee at a time it might not be too bad? i suppose with long time frames likely to be involved it may still be slow)

Answer (score 0):

I added some records to the sample data to address the issue raised surrounding the possibility of a `PersonID` having more than one time range where the `PersonID` has the same `Title` and `Salary`.

**Answer:**

```
create table dbo.Salary
    (
        PersonID varchar(3)
        , StartDate date
        , EndDate date
        , Salary int
    )

create table dbo.Title
    (
        PersonID varchar(3)
        , StartDate date
        , EndDate date
        , Title varchar(10)
    )

insert into dbo.Salary
values ('Me', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', 2000)
    , ('Me', '2017-02-01', '2017-05-31', 2100)
    , ('Me', '2017-06-01', '2017-07-31', 2300)
    , ('You', '2017-01-01', '2017-03-31', 2400)
    , ('You', '2017-04-01', '2017-08-31', 2500)
    , ('You', '2017-09-01', '2017-12-31', 2400)     

insert into dbo.Title
values ('Me', '2017-01-01', '2017-03-31', 'Junior')
     , ('Me', '2017-04-01', '2017-07-31', 'Senior')
     , ('You', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-28', 'Junior')
     , ('You', '2017-03-01', '2017-05-31', 'Senior')
     , ('You', '2017-06-01', '2017-12-31', 'Junior')

select a.PersonID
, a.StartDate
, a.EndDate
, a.Salary
, a.Title
from (
    select s.PersonID
    , iif(s.StartDate < t.StartDate, t.StartDate, s.StartDate) as StartDate
    , iif(s.EndDate < t.EndDate, s.EndDate, t.EndDate) as EndDate
    , s.Salary
    , t.Title
    from dbo.Salary as s
    inner join dbo.Title as t on s.PersonID = t.PersonID
    ) as a
where 1=1
and datediff(d, a.StartDate, a.EndDate) >= 0 --is it a valid time range?
```

The sub-query duplicates all possible `StartDate` / `EndDate` combinations for a `PersonID`, and the outer query determines if that time range is valid.

**Output:**

```
PersonID    StartDate    EndDate     Salary  Title
Me          2017-01-01   2017-01-31  2000    Junior
Me          2017-02-01   2017-03-31  2100    Junior
Me          2017-04-01   2017-05-31  2100    Senior
Me          2017-06-01   2017-07-31  2300    Senior
You         2017-01-01   2017-02-28  2400    Junior
You         2017-03-01   2017-03-31  2400    Senior
You         2017-04-01   2017-05-31  2500    Senior
You         2017-06-01   2017-08-31  2500    Junior
You         2017-09-01   2017-12-31  2400    Junior
```